# Top 50 emails from Outlook from new to old

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How do I get the top 50 emails from Outlook using Excel VBA from new to old?

I am using the code below, however this is fetching the emails from last to first.

```
Sub GetFromInbox()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

i = 1
x = Date

For Each olMail In Fldr.Items

    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = olMail.Subject
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = olMail.ReceivedTime
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = olMail.SenderName
    i = i + 1

Next olMail

Set Fldr = Nothing
Set olNs = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see any mention of '50' in the logic.

Comment: Hi nicomp I tried to get the outpoot from this but was not able to get it however I am using if I < 51 logic here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort a collection of the items in the folder.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetFromInbox()

Dim olApp As outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder

Dim sortItems As Items
Dim olObj As Object

Dim i As Long
Dim maxIter As Long

Set olApp = New outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

' Sort a collection of items, not Fldr.Items
Set sortItems = Fldr.Items
sortItems.Sort "[Received]", True

If sortItems.count > 50 Then
    maxIter = 50
Else
    maxIter = sortItems.count
End If

For i = 1 To maxIter

    Set olObj = sortItems(i)

    If olObj.Class = olMail Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = olObj.subject
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = olObj.ReceivedTime
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = olObj.senderName
    End If

Next

Set olObj = Nothing
Set sortItems = Nothing
Set Fldr = Nothing
Set olNs = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If this grabs the wrong 50 emails you can try stepping through items the opposite way like:

```
For i = Fldr.Items.Count To Fldr.Items.Count - 50 Step -1
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = Fldr.Items(i).Subject
etc...
```

Add an `exit` once you hit 50, for ex:

```
If counter = 50 Then Exit For
```

Also, you can alternatively keep your existing code, then add a function to `sort` the emails by received date and only keep the top 50